# PHPUnit Error: Class not found

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, symfony4

I'm using symfony 4.0 and using "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.0" in composer.json.
I have installed phpunit-bridge using command

`composer require --dev phpunit`.

Now when I run `vendor\bin\simple-phpunit tests/Handler`   It shows  this error

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\symfonydemo>vendor\bin\simple-phpunit tests/Handler
PHPUnit 6.3.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing tests/Handler
E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 173 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) App\Tests\Handler\CalculatorResultHandlerTest::testWalkTime
Error: Class 'App\Service\CalculateWalk' not found

C:\xampp\htdocs\symfonydemo\tests\Handler\CalculatorResultHandlerTest.php:19

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

C:\xampp\htdocs\symfonydemo>
```

**App\Tests\Handler\CalculatorResultHandlerTest:**

```
namespace App\Tests\Handler;

use App\Service\CalculateWalk;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class CalculatorResultHandlerTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testWalkTime(){
        $walkObj = new CalculateWalk();
        $time = $walkObj->calculateTime('20000');
        $this->assertEquals('40',$time,'Walk minutes are wrong.');
    }

}
```

**vendor/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-6.3/phpunit.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
         verbose="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="small">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/Framework</directory>
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/Runner</directory>
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/Util</directory>
            <directory>tests</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="large">
            <directory suffix=".phpt">tests/TextUI</directory>
            <directory suffix=".phpt">tests/Regression</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <file>src/Framework/Assert/Functions.php</file>
                <file>src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <php>
        <const name="PHPUNIT_TESTSUITE" value="true"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "symfony/console": "^4.0",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.0",
        "symfony/form": "^4.0",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
        "symfony/security-csrf": "^4.0",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/validator": "^4.0",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/debug-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/dotenv": "^4.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.0",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "^4.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install --symlink --relative %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "id": "01C41AEMAEYWEXNQZJ9Q0FBVGW",
            "allow-contrib": false
        }
    }
}
```

**Path of CalculateWalk Class:**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\symfonydemo\src\Service\CalculateWalk.php
```

**src\Service\CalculateWalk.php**

```
namespace App\Service;


use App\Interfaces\CalculateResultInterface;

class CalculateWalk implements CalculateResultInterface
{
    public const WALK = 500;
    public function calculateTime($meters)
    {
        $minutes = $meters / self::WALK;
        $seconds = $minutes * 60;
        $time['hours'] = floor($seconds / 3600);
        $time['mins'] = floor($seconds / 60 % 60);
        $time['secs'] = floor($seconds % 60);
        return $time;
    }
}
```

Can anyone please me to resolve this error. Thanks.

Comment: Show your composer.json.

Comment: run `composer du`

Comment: @commonsense Added composer.json

Comment: @MahdiYounesi I run composer du. It's generated autoload files. But again it's showing same error when i run tests.

Comment: Can you post the full file path of `App\Service\CalculateWalk`?

Comment: @commonsense here it is  C:\xampp\htdocs\symfonydemo\src\Service\CalculateWalk.php

Comment: What if you use `"": "src/"` in composer autoload?

Comment: @SenseException It didn't work, after updating "":"src/", composer install showing error "Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Kernel" from namespace "App".
"

Comment: check your services_test.yaml, yo need to add the autoloader, like services.yaml

Answer (score 1):

Happening in 4.1 as well, possibly an issue in the bin/phpunit script:

```
$classLoader->unregister();
```

I worked around it by creating a tests/bootstrap.php file (and updating phpunit.xml.dist to use it):

```
<?php

$classLoader = require dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload.php';
$classLoader->register(true);
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer would you plz explain what is difference btwn`$kernel = new \App\Kernel('test', true);
$kernel->boot();` and `$classLoader->register(true);` because in my bottstrap file they 2 options works

Answer (score 1):

In your phpunit.xml, you maybe need to specify the kernel and environment :

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.5/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <env name="KERNEL_CLASS" value="App\Kernel" />
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="test" />
        <env name="APP_DEBUG" value="1" />
        <env name="SHELL_VERBOSITY" value="-1" />
  </php>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just had this problem.
Not sure why, but I didn't have a phpunit.xml.dist in the root of my project.
None of the examples shows this, but if you add bootstrap= and then include the autoloaded. It should start to find your classes.

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.0/phpunit.xsd"
     bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
```

>

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this problem because I forgot to run `composer auto-dump -o` after installing phpunit.