# Testing a service in Symfony4 : class not found

Tags: php, phpunit, symfony4

I want to test my service in Symfony 4 using phpunit bridge, but when i launch the test i get :

```
Error: Class 'App\Service\CompanyManager' not found
```

My service is located at src/Service/CompanyManager.php

**tests/Service/CompanyManagerTest.php** :

```
namespace App\Tests\Service;

use App\Service\CompanyManager;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use App\Entity\Company;

class CompanyManagerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testGetCompany()
    {
        $companyManager = new CompanyManager();
        $company = $companyManager->getCompany(2);
        $this->assertInstanceOf(Company::class,$company);
        $company = $companyManager->getCompany(1000);
        $this->assertNull($company);
    }
}
```

In config/services_test.yaml, there is this statement :

```
# If you need to access services in a test, create an alias
# and then fetch that alias from the container. As a convention,
# aliases are prefixed with test. For example:
#
# test.App\Service\MyService: '@App\Service\MyService'
```

So i tried to add :

```
test.App\Service\CompanyManager: '@App\Service\CompanyManager'
```

But i still get the error :

```
$ ./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit tests
PHPUnit 5.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing tests
E                                                                   1 / 1 
(100%)

Time: 364 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) App\Tests\Service\CompanyManagerTest::testGetCompany
Error: Class 'App\Service\CompanyManager' not found

C:\...\web\vp20\tests\Service\CompanyManagerTest.php:22
```

Line 22 is :

```
$companyManager = new CompanyManager();
```

Any idea ?

PS : sounds like someone has the same problem there : [PHPUnit Error: Class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440291/phpunit-error-class-not-found)

Comment: you checked class `App\Service\CompanyManager` yet?

Comment: yes the class is there, 100% sure

Comment: you can try include full path of class `CompanyManager` for test :3 just bad idea I can think. :))

Comment: Sounds most likely to be an issue with the class autoload. Could you verify that the app path is defined in `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php`?

Comment: i think it is : 'App\\Tests\\' => array($baseDir . '/tests'),
    'App\\' => array($baseDir . '/src'),

Answer (score 6):

I have just had this problem.
Not sure why, but I didn't have a `phpunit.xml.dist` in the root of my project.
None of the examples shows this, but if you add `bootstrap=` and then include the autoloaded. It should start to find your classes.

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.0/phpunit.xsd"
     bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
>
```

Comment: In my case I had `phpunit.xml.dist` but `bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"` was missing from it. Note: I am using Symfony 3.4. After adding bootstrap information, It stopped complaining about missing Entity class.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue in my case

Answer (score 0):

I think you should extend `KernelTestCase` (`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase`) instead of `TestCase`

Comment: Results in PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase' not found in (...)\tests\Service\CompanyManagerTest.php on line 18

Comment: did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49571043/testing-a-service-in-symfony4-class-not-found/49630595?noredirect=1#comment86173409_49571043

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that a new class is not yet present in composers list. So... try to run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

I'll suggest to use this composer configuration

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": ["src", "testS"]
        }
    }
}
```

Once you've defined this autoloading configuration in composer.json, and after a `composer dump-autoload` you should never have issues with autoloading.

Comment: I tried, but still the same problem... i think it's a problem related with symfony 4, maybe in relation with this subject : https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/8097